# Domain Users Unable to Access Home Directory Without Sharing Folder

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, filesystems, user-permissions

So I run a windows 2012 r2 for a client with 20-30 employees. I have created a home directory for each person as a means to save data onto the server. However, recently new users that are added are unable to access their personal folder without the folder being shared and exposing the folder to the rest of the system. For instance, when you select the server from the network panel, a users home directory can be seen. Is there a way I can share a folder without exposing it to the rest of the system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is two easy way, first make sure the permission is setup correctly, to allow only the user on the folder. Any 'everyone' or such right will list the folder to everyone else.

A good way to do it is to share a root folder, like if your home folder is in c:\home\userX, you share the home (c:\home), and you map \server\home\userX from the user session. You make sure all users folder are correctly setup for the security, to not allow everyone.

Second, you can create a share with a $ at the end, that will hide the share, but if the folder security is badly setup, an user can still guess a folder name a navigate into it.

So my advice is to create correct security for all your home folder please.

Comment: I have the correct security permissions in place. What's interesting is that this is only happening to new users that have been added. I've done the mapping on the user session and it still doesn't seem to work. The drive will be mapped but the user is unable to make any changes within it.

Comment: As for the sharing with the $. Are you saying I create a share name with a '$' at the end and that will remove the drive from being visible?

Comment: @ConnorTaormina It will remove it from the view, but to make sure, visible by where you mean ? like in file explorer from a remote computer ?